# C code / BMI / need help please - BMI value result always wrong

Tags: c

This is my first post, so if something goes wrong, sorry xD

Basically, i'm helping a friend in his C class, and i'm leaning at the same time, well, literally the basic there

This probably is something basic, that we don't know how to correct, the problem is: the BMI value is getting aways "0" and the "bmi corrected" doesn't shows the results, he just end the code, ah, yeah, the addition(+54) and subtraction(-93), they are flat values that the teacher asks to put.


Can you guys help us?

 edit: i solved the problem about always show 0, we didn't put a dot in the height value

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main (){
  float bmi, height, weight, valueone, valuetwo;
  printf("please your height: ");
  scanf(" %f", &height);
  printf("please your weight : ");
  scanf(" %f", &weight);

  bmi = weight/(height*height);
  printf("bmi=", &bmi);

  valueone = bmi + 54;
  valoetwo = valueone - 93;
  printf("BMI corrected: ", &valoetwo);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With the use of the non-existent variable `valoetwo`, that won't even compile. And printing `&bmi` will use the address of that variable, not its value. Read the warnings, the compiler doesn't spit them out for its *own* amusement  :-)

Answer (score -3):

If you correct errors it would compile and seems to produce some value, not sure if it really is what you want...

```
  float bmi, height, weight, valueone, valuetwo;
  printf("please your height: ");
  scanf(" %f", &height);
  printf("please your weight : ");
  scanf(" %f", &weight);

  bmi = weight/(height*height);
  printf("bmi=%0.6f\n", bmi);

  valueone = bmi + 54;
  valuetwo = valueone - 93;
  printf("BMI corrected: %f\n", valuetwo);
  return 0;
```

Comment: my hero doesn't wears capes, he fixes my codes <3 
thanks a lot, it worked

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.